# Cannot build and debug because the active file is not a C or C++ source file

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc

I'm trying to run a c program file. This is what I get from the terminal when I run the code

I am trying to run it from the output window but I get an error when I do it. I installed code runner as well as gcc and the code is running well in the windows cmd. [output from the terminal window[output from the output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjutV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crQdw.png)

Comment: Connecting stdout, and stderr to random files in your directory is a horrendous idea.  You'll lose the contents as they get replaced by the debugger console output.  Connecting stdin to random files isn't much better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just a guess, but it appears the debugger is looking for your source code and not finding it. Visual studio code appears to have launch configuration file that may be incorrect. Are you running it as shown here?  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: @Jay the launch configuration file does not seem to to have anything missing

Comment: @BenVoigt how are they connected? I'm a bit of a novice.. and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the "program" value in the config the source code not the executable?

Comment: @Jay it is executable

Comment: In the example shown in the link it has the source code file name in the "program" setting

Comment: yes in the program setting there is the source code file path.